# How to run all form submitted data through function

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-injection

In classic ASP, is there an easy way to sanitize all form submitted input?  This is my sanitizing function:

```
function dbsafe(data)
data = replace(data,";","")
data = replace(data,"'","")
data = replace(data,"â€”","")
data = replace(data,"/*","")
data = replace(data,"*/","")
data = replace(data,"*","")
data = replace(data,"/","")
data = replace(data,"xp_","")
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

I would instead consider using parameterized queries.  Attackers will eventually think of something you have forgotten to remove.

Here is a link on parameterized queries: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190

Comment: Oddly enough, I am using parametrized queries (built through Dreamweaver).  I didn't build this app nor do I use Dreamweaver, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog posting from the IIS team that seems to be working well:

http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/04/28/filtering-sql-injection-from-classic-asp.aspx